# gdaladdo - Large file, BIGTIFF

Tags: gdal, gdaladdo

Using GDAL 3.5.0, and running gdaladdo on a large number of DTM hillshades (in a VRT) as follows:

`gdaladdo hillshade.vrt -r lanczos --config BIGTIFF_OVERVIEW YES --config GDAL_NUM_THREADS ALL_CPUS --config BIGTIFF YES --config COMPRESS_OVERVIEW JPEG 8 16 32 64 128`

I am making it to approximately 70% before gdaladdo fails with the following:

`0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70.ERROR 1: TIFFAppendToStrip:Maximum TIFF file size exceeded. Use BIGTIFF=YES creation option.`

I am wondering if anyone has run into this and has had any success generating large pyramids? As the command above shows I am attempting to follow the programs instruction, but that fails.

Update:
gdalinfo on the VRT:

```
 gdalinfo hillshade.vrt
Driver: VRT/Virtual Raster
Files: B01_009886_1658_XN_14S184W__P21_009385_1658_XN_14S184W_ba-aligned-DEM-geoid-hs.vrt
       B01_009966_1730_XN_07S208W__B01_010111_1730_XN_07S208W_ba-aligned-DEM-geoid-hs.vrt
... #OMITTED 3765 other VRTs
Size is 1055091, 206422
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCRS["Mars_2000_(Sphere)",
    DATUM["Mars_2000_(Sphere)",
        ELLIPSOID["Mars_2000_(Sphere)",3396190,0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
    PRIMEM["Reference_Meridian",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    ID["ESRI",104971]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
Origin = (-179.765478797399908,35.206461943592807)
Pixel Size = (0.000340743801124,-0.000340743801124)
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-179.7654788,  35.2064619) (179d45'55.72"W, 35d12'23.26"N)
Lower Left  (-179.7654788, -35.1305550) (179d45'55.72"W, 35d 7'50.00"S)
Upper Right ( 179.7502391,  35.2064619) (179d45' 0.86"E, 35d12'23.26"N)
Lower Right ( 179.7502391, -35.1305550) (179d45' 0.86"E, 35d 7'50.00"S)
Center      (  -0.0076199,   0.0379535) (  0d 0'27.43"W,  0d 2'16.63"N)
Band 1 Block=128x128 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=0
  Overviews: 65944x12902, 32972x6451, 16486x3226, 8243x1613, 131887x25803, 4122x807
```

Comment: I think you missed the `=` sign in `BIGTIFF=YES`.

Comment: I did try that. Adding the '=' results in `FAILURE: Too many command options.`

Comment: The right syntax for configuration options is indeed `--config key value`. Could you add gdalinfo from the .vrt? Have you tried with `-ro`? It shouldn't make difference because the overviews for vrt are always external.

Comment: The error message actually suggests using a creation option `-co BIGTIFF=YES`, not a configuration option. That is odd because gdaladdo does not support creation options.

Comment: @user30184 See below, `-co` can not be passed to gdaladdo in 3.5.0. I can pass `-oo` for open options, but that doesn't help here.

Comment: Right. Have you already tried with read-only `-ro`? How about providing gdalinfo about the vrt?

Comment: The following worked: `gdaladdo hillshade.vrt -r lanczos --config SPARSE_OK_OVERVIEW ON --config BIGTIFF_OVERVIEW YES --config GDAL_NUM_THREADS ALL_CPUS --config COMPRESS_OVERVIEW JPEG 8 16 32 64 128 256 -ro`. But I think that this is a red herring. The use of the SPARSE_OK_OVERVIEW ON results in an ovr file that is <200M. If I omit that the file is > 4GB and errors.

Comment: Edit the post with code working to help future developers

Answer (score 1):

The raised error `Use BIGTIFF=YES creation option` indicates a need of  **creation option**

change your code to

```
gdaladdo hillshade.vrt -r lanczos --config BIGTIFF_OVERVIEW YES --config GDAL_NUM_THREADS ALL_CPUS -co BIGTIFF=YES --config COMPRESS_OVERVIEW JPEG 8 16 32 64 128
```

remember put  **=** between **tag** and **value** creation options

Comment: @user30184 and MarcoReliquias huge thanks! I had not realized the difference between -co and --config.

Comment: Update: I tested with -co and it does not look like gdaladdo accepts configuration options. Attempting to pass `-co` fails.

Comment: `FAILURE: Unknown option name '-co'`